# Printing each elements of one row on separate lines?

Tags: java, arrays

This is my question:
Assume a two-dimensional array of ints called 'myInts'. Write a code snippet that will print each of the elements of row m on a separate line. You may assume that m is not out of bounds.

This is the work I have done but I am not sure I am going in the right direction...

```
for (int i = 0; i < myInts.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < myInts[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print (myInts[i][j]);

        if(j < myInts[i].length - 1) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your requirement is only to print the values of a given *row* `m`, I think you only need a single `for` loop, to iterate over that single row:

```
public void printRow(int[][] array, int m) {
    for (int i=0; i < array[m].length; ++i) {
        System.out.println(array[m][i]);
    }
}
```

I didn't bother checking the bounds of input `m`, because you said we don't need to.  But in any case, `printRow()` would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` should the index `m` be out of bounds.